# (co)Limits of naturally isomorphic functors

Tags: category-theory

Let $F,G$ be naturally isomorphic functors from $\mathsf C$ to $\mathsf D$.

How are the limits of colimits of these functors related? Does the existence of one guarantee the existence of the other?

Comment: Of course they're the same. There is an obvious isomorphism between the category of (co)cones on $F$ and the category of (co)cones on $G$.

Comment: @ZhenLin thanks. Could you please post this as an answer so I can accept?